# SwiftUI: allow navigation bar to appear ONLY on the main/first page

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationbar, swiftui, swift5

I have written a simply formatted code, showing that if navigation bar is allowed to appear on the first/main page, by using `.navigationBarTitle(...)`, the subview(s) of that page will have navigation bar.

Main View:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
                NavigationLink(destination: View01()){
                    Text("To view 1")
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Front Page", displayMode: .inline) //removable, but needed for the first page's bar
        }
    }
}
```

Child view of the main view:

```
struct View01: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            EmptyView()
        }
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true) //the back button is gone 
        .navigationBarHidden(true) //this has no effect here
    }
}
```

When I remove `.navigationBarTitle(...)` from the main code, the navigation bar disappears from all views. However, if I put it back and use `.navigationBarHidden(true)` in the child view code, the navigation bar remains here.

I'm looking for any solution which allows me to have a navigation bar appears ONLY on the first/front/main page, while the other pages/child pages do not have a navigation bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If do you want to use **push** and **pop**,
Please try this way:

```
struct ParentView: View {
    @State var navigationBarIsHidden: Bool = false
    @State private var showDetail = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color.red
                NavigationLink("show child view", destination: ChildView(navigationBarIsHidden: $navigationBarIsHidden, showSelf: $showDetail), isActive: $showDetail)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("title", displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarHidden(navigationBarIsHidden)
            .onAppear {
                self.navigationBarIsHidden = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ChildView.swift**

```
struct ChildView: View {
    @Binding var navigationBarIsHidden: Bool
    @Binding var showSelf: Bool
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.green
            Text("ChildView").onTapGesture {
                self.navigationBarIsHidden = false
                self.showSelf = false
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            self.navigationBarIsHidden = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and did you find a way to appear again when pop the child view (programmatically) on a button click

Comment: I'm afraid this does not work in the long run. For example, if I use `@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>` with a back button with action `self.navigationBarIsHidden = false` and `self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()`, after arriving to main page, the navigation bar did not appear back. Any idea why?

Comment: @jpulikkottil
Thanks.
I updated code, please test again.